# Information about Lotus Explorer bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, commuter, single-speed

I just bought a 20" Lotus Explorer for $200. The frame is Tange CR-MO and has Shimano components, the bike shop guy said it was a good frame. I don't know a lot about bikes; I'm just looking for a bike to get back and forth to school. Also theres a sticker on the fork that says "CR-MO uni-lite plus". He also switched it to single-speed and put new tires on it for me.

Any information about Lotus bikes would be helpful because I can't find much.

Comment: Isn't this the kind of question you should ask _before_ buying it?

Comment: The "did I get ripped off" part of this question is very difficult to answer and really super-specific. Depends on your local market, the condition of the bike, the exact components, etc, etc. So I edited this into more of a "information about the bike" question that may lead to enough information for you to decide if it was a good price.

Answer (score 3):

Your Lotus Explorer was introduced in 1987 and is not a common bicycle. We do not know if the bicycle was offered past 1987, but by then Lotus as a bicycle company seems to have been winding down their production. 1988 versions of 1987 models are not common. Lotus was known more for their road bikes and it seems their BMX models and some of their ATB models are not found very often.  The first Lotus ATB was the Pegasus introduced around 1983-ish, then they added the more affordable Viking to the line by 1986.  In 1987 Lotus jumped to 6 ATB models, the Pegasus, Cherokee, Viking, Explorer, Express and Commuter (listed from the top of the line to entry level).

The Explorer had a suggested price of $359.95 in 1987 and came in Crimson and Forest Green.  Lotus advertised the bike as "moderately priced with true off-road designing and componentry".

The bicycle also featured 2" tires, oversized Cro/Mo tubing and 15-speed gearing.

I think $200.00 was an okay price to pay for the bike and it should suit your needs well.

Tim, [www.VintageLOTUSbicycles.com](http://www.VintageLOTUSbicycles.com)

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://www.socalmtb.com/messages/road/messages/1662.htm):

> Lotus Bicycles is/was based in Pennsylvania:
>
> Last known mailing address/telephone number below:
>
> Lotus Bicycles Post Office Box 21924 Lehigh Valley, Pennsylvania
>   18002-1924
>   +800-841-0123 Founded in 1979
>
> They had a website in 2000 : www.lotusbike.com but it is no longer
>   registered/active. They manufactured bicycles & frames for road &
>   track use.

From what I read it used to be a pretty good brand -- what one might buy if they were a dedicated amateur rider but not uber-rich.  But apparently they never made it out of the early 90s, when frame-building technology changed (and it became impossible to compete on price with the larger automated manufacturers).

Here is a web site on them:  http://www.vintagelotusbicycles.com/